# Creating the user's specific directory in R

Tags: r

I want to read the CSV file "mydata.csv" as an input and create the output in the same directory using R. I have hard-coded for getting csv input(Domain_test.csv) and the output(MyData.csv) path as below. But  I will have to share the same Rscript and the corresponding csv files with one of the users so that he/she can execute it and take the results. I want the user should to select his specific path where ever he wants and make it run without hard coding the input/output path in the script.

How it should be done in R?

```
#reading csv from this current directory
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/Desktop/input_output_directory/Domain_test.csv")

#generating the output In this same directory
write.csv(dataframe,"C:/Users/Desktop/input_output_directory/MyData.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

`wd <- choose.dir(default = "", caption = "Select folder")`

`setwd(wd)`

Comment: You can do this, but I would suggest you tell your users to move the data to a folder called "Data" that is in the folder that contains the script. Good programming practice. You can use the package `here` so they can run the script from any folder.

Comment: Which package that you suggest here?

Comment: @`harish T` - The package is called `here`. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/here/vignettes/here.html